# How to binding C array type in objective-c library using Objective Sharpie?

Tags: objective-c, c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

The method that I need to bind have argument in primitive array for example:

```
(bool)isRectangle:(const CGPoint[4])corners;
```

How I bind `const CGPoint[4]` type with C# type?

Note: Using Sharpie, the result is below

```
[Static]
[Export("isRectangle:")]
void IsRectangle(CGPoint[] corners);
```

and when I build it, I got error

```
cannot convert from 'CoreGraphics.CGPoint[]' to 'Foundation.NSObject'
```

Comment: CGPoint is struct defined in oc, refer to here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference/#BindAsAttribute maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `const CGPoint[4]` as struct in your `StructsAndEnums.cs`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rectangle
{
    public CGPoint leftTop;
    public CGPoint rightTop;
    public CGPoint leftBotton;
    public CGPoint rightBotton;
}
```

Your definition becomes:

```
//(bool)isRectangle:(const CGPoint[4])corners;
[Export("isRectangle:")]
bool IsRectangle(Rectangle corners);
```